# How are tasks divided up with compute shaders?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

how does a compute shader divide up tasks?

```
#version 430 core
layout (local_size_x = 64) in;


layout(std430, binding=4 ) buffer INFO 
{
        vec2 info[];
};


void main()
{

    uint gid = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    info[gid].x += 1.0;
    info[gid].y += 1.0;
    memoryBarrier();
}
```

in this example, by specifying local_size_x=64, does that mean that each work group will automatically have 64 threads, and since the input is a vec2 array, it knows to just go through main with each vec2 on a separate thread?

Also, what would i do if the shader were to generate 10 vec2 for every vec2 input and then i wanted to do something different with each of those, each on a separate thread. The initial 64 threads would branch into 640. Can this be done in this same shader or would i have to make a second one?

Answer (score 3):

> in this example, by specifying local_size_x=64, does that mean that each work group will automatically have 64 threads, and since the input is a vec2 array, it knows to just go through main with each vec2 on a separate thread?

Yes, that's how the [invocations within a work group are defined](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader#Overview).

> Also, what would i do if the shader were to generate 10 vec2 for every vec2 input and then i wanted to do something different with each of those, each on a separate thread.

How you do that is entirely up to you. But yes, it would have to be a different shader. Compute shaders cannot *create* invocations. Not directly.

The purpose of having work items within a work group is to allow those local invocations to communicate with each other and help them compute something. If you don't have any [`shared` variables or `barrier` calls](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_variables), then it doesn't really matter what your local size is (well, not from a functionality perspective. Local size can affect performance).

As such, you should pick your local size based on how much work you intend to shove at a particular dispatch operation. Right now, you must process `vec2`s in integer multiples of 64. If many invocations of the same group are reading the same values, then you need to re-evaluate how much work a full group will do.

The limitation on the number of invocations within a work group is hardware-dependent, but will be no less than 1024. So you've got some room to play with.

In your new system, if you still want a work group invocation to process 64 inputs, then obviously a work group will have to have a local size totaling 640. I would probably suggest a smaller granularity like 8, leaving your local size at a total of 80.

Whatever size you choose, the best way to actually specify this is by using the fact that the local size has multiple dimensions. The X dimension should refer to the input index, with the Y dimension being the output index from the X's input. So the Y size would be 10, with the X size being 8 or 64 or whatever you want.

Therefore, when you go to fetch your input, the index you need is:

```
const uvec3 size_mult = {1, gl_NumWorkGroups.x, gl_NumWorkGroups.x * gl_NumWorkGroups.y};
const uint input_index = gl_WorkGroupSize.x * dot(gl_WorkGroupID, size_mult) + gl_LocalInvocationID.x;
```

The index for the output would be:

```
const uint output_index = gl_WorkGroupSize.y * input_index + gl_LocalInvocationID.y;
```